# Angular 2+ FullCalendar Custom View

Tags: angular, custom-view, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am currently using Angular2/4 version of FullCalendar from this link https://github.com/Jamaks/ng-fullcalendar

Does anyone know how to add a new custom view? I need to introduce a custom 10 days agendaWeek view but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Can any expert out there point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This module is a wrapper, I assume it channels the settings to `fullcalendar`. If these settings can be used, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings, then you should be able to amend the style of the view a bit.

If the above doesn't help you, you need to extend the view by extending the library, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js. In that case, you need to build 'fullcalendar', your plugin, and your app together. There's a chance you might not be able to use `ng-fullcalendar`.

Another thing, I used this in the past, https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/tree/master/src/modules, they implemented all views, you can read about it if you are interested. But I don't see either way is easy or quick.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I suspect there is no easy way but extending the source of the ng-fullcalendar.

Comment: hey @developer did you find a solution for this